# Static nested grids using Susy

Tags: sass, breakpoints, susy-sass

I am experimenting static layout with Susy and I need some directions on how to establish a nested grid with same gutter width. In this example below, I have .main that spans 9 columns out of 12 columns and I like to make its children .main-item to have a four column layout inside the 9 column layout by maintaining the same 18px gutter width.

http://sassmeister.com/gist/2a414c2b9dc6f332b89b

This of course works seamlessly in fluid grid because everything is in percentages, but in this experiment I want to try with static grid.

What is the best way to do this? Is "with-layout" mixin only the possible solution to achieve this by defining a new layout or are there any other ways to achieve this?

What I have tried so far:
1. Simply mentioning span(3 of 12) for .main-item knowing it wont work, but still gave it a shot
2. Defining a new layout and using with-layout mixin, but it threw me this error "Function valid-column-math finished without @return". I guess I would have done it wrong.

Appreciate your advise.

Answer (score 0):

Re-defining the grid will take a lot of extra math, because you would have to calculate the new size of a column. Also, context doesn't matter, since the math is not relative to context. It seems to work if you just span fractional columns, though. You want to divide 9 columns into 4, so that would look something like:

```
.main-item {
  @include span(9/4);
  &.last{
    @include last;
  }
}
```